# WSDL: How to define operation/message which accepts any XML document as input and output (for python zeep client)

Tags: xml, wsdl, zeep

I have to communicate with some kind of proxy service which gets an XML document in-lined inside `<Body>` and passes it further. The problem is that this service provides broken WSDL with operation defined as `operation() -> None` but it actually needs `operation(any-xml) -> any-xml`.

I can edit this WSDL and provide it to my client generator (python zeep) but I don't know how to define WSDL operation accepting any XML structure.

Comment: Did you find a solution by now?

Comment: No. I've overcome it by "hacking" the client library: I've created a proxy inside zeep client which injects XML document into request's body.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet for that? Then I will try that, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've overcome this problem with quite a dirty hack. `zeep` has support for plugins and those plugins can modify requests. My plugin injects XML document into `soap-env:Body`. Here is the documentation on how to setup your own plugin: https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html

My plugin looks like this:

```py
from lxml import etree
from zeep import Plugin
from typing import Optional
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

namespaces = {"soap-env": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"}


class MyInterceptingPlugin(Plugin):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.xml: Optional[ET.Element] = None

    def ingress(self, envelope, http_headers, __operation__):
        return envelope, http_headers

    def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, __operation__, __binding_options__):
        if self.xml is not None:
            body = envelope.find("./soap-env:Body", namespaces)
            body.append(self.xml)
        return envelope, http_headers
```

Before every call to this problematic method I have to set on the instance of this plugin:

`my_plugin.xml = element_tree_root`

And then unset it.